# Hook 32bit Process In 64bit Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook

I get a problem when I using keyboard hook on window7 64bit.
I do these things:
 1. Create a 32bit dll
 2. Load it to application and setWindowHookEx

I've hooked successfully on 32bit application (Y!M, Skype...) but when I hooked on my desktop or any 64bit application (notepad) that application come freezes until I stop my hook application.
I create 64bit dll, do the same at above, and get the same problem with 32bit process.

So, I think the problem is in my 32bit dll, can't be injected to 64bit process. But I don't know how can I inject 64bit dll to process when window is focusing on it.

I want to know any way to do it, and how to do it. Or can I only hook on 32bit process and don't hook on 64bit process, can you show me the way to do it.
Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to create a 64-bit app to hook 64-bit processes.  So you basically need 3 processes, one for hooking 32-bit apps, one for 64-bit apps and one that coordinates them.  Avoid all this by using a low-level keyboard hook, it doesn't require injecting a DLL.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you cannot load a 32-bit DLL into a 64-bit process, or a 64-bit DLL into a 32-bit process. From [Programming Guide for 64-bit Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384249.aspx):

> ... 32-bit processes cannot load 64-bit DLLs for execution, and 64-bit processes cannot load 32-bit DLLs for execution.

You will need to have two versions of your DLL: 32-bit and 64-bit. But that is only a part solution. Additionally, you will need to determine the architecture of the process into which you want to load your DLL. The WINAPI function [`GetBinaryType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364819%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can determine that, but it takes a path to a binary which your code must acquire.

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain me for more details, how can I do it.

Comment: `IsWow64Process` will be a much more useful API than `GetBinaryType`.